# Magento 2 : Custom grid cannot export to csv or XML

Tags: magento2, grid, csv

I've created custom grid block using UI component but I can not export it to csv file.

I'm getting the error:

```
Undefined index: attributes in vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory.php on line 166
```

My module is here: https://github.com/helmsmantest/M2-Custom-grid

Comment: Your code looks legit. Try to remove parts from the ui component xml to to isolate the problem. Or check how `$componentData` looks like in  `UiComponentFactory::argumentsResolver`, the method that reports the error.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a selections column element. See this example from sales_order_grid.xml (replace the indexField with the primary key from your model):

```
<selectionsColumn name="ids">
    <settings>
        <indexField>entity_id</indexField>
    </settings>
</selectionsColumn>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your file pass the following selection column after `<columns name="orders_list_columns">`. https://github.com/helmsmantest/M2-Custom-grid/blob/master/app/code/BroSolutions/OrdersExport/view/adminhtml/ui_component/orders_list.xml

```
<selectionsColumn name="ids">
    <settings>
        <indexField>entity_id</indexField>
    </settings>
</selectionsColumn>
```

Also update exportButton tag

```
<exportButton name="export_button">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">orders_list.orders_list_columns.ids</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </exportButton>
```